# zf2 validation form: How can I validate dependent fields?

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

I have 5 text form

```
$number1 = new Text('number-1');
$number2 = new Text('number-2');
$number3 = new Text('number-3');
....
```

with the relative filters

```
foreach(...)
   $input = new Input($elementName);
   $validator = new ValidatorChain();
   $validator->addByName('Int')
       ->addByName('Between', array(
          'min'=>0,
          'max'=>$this->maxAllowedTicket,
          'inclusive'=>true));
   $filter = new FilterChain();
   $filter->attachByName('Int');

   $input->setValidatorChain($validator);
   $input->setFilterChain($filter);
```

I would that only one of this 3 forms can contain a value different from 0.
There are then two possible errors.

TOO MANY NUMBERS

```
 $data['number1'] = 5;
 $data['number2'] = 5;
 $data['number3'] = 0;
 $data['number4'] = 5;
 $data['number5'] = 0;
```

NO NUMBER

```
 $data['number1'] = 0;
 $data['number2'] = 0;
 $data['number3'] = 0;
 $data['number4'] = 0;
 $data['number5'] = 0;
```

How can I validate this multiple fields at the same time ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to write your own `Validator` class to do so. The `isValid()` method of your new validation class also receives the `$context` which includes the values of the whole form. This way you can validate the value of each field depending on the other fields.

```
namespace My\Validator;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class CustomValidator extends AbstractValidator
{
    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        // put your logic here and call
        // $this->error(); if required
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! it works, but how can I register this translator in ValidatorPluginManager?

Comment: dunno, not using this, but you can just pass the full classname (string) as name for the validator in an input specification

Answer (score 0):

Craft your own solution using the Callback validator.

Examples are here: http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#callback